# how to compile mariadb to get libmysqlclient.so? (missing libmysqlclient.so in /usr/local/mysql/lib)

Tags: c++, mysql, compilation, cmake, mariadb

I wanted to move our database from mysql (community version) to mariadb with the further use of php7.1/apache2.4.25... So I have to compile mariadb in our new production environment. I compiled it with these options:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING="-std=c++11" -DCONC_WITH_CURL=ON -DCONC_WITH_EXTERNAL_ZLIB=ON -DDISABLE_SHARED=OFF -DCONC_WITH_MYSQLCOMPAT:BOOL=ON -DPLUGIN_CLIENT_ED25519:STRING=DYNAMIC .
make all && make install
```

The mysql community version has a libmysqlclient.so in /usr/local/mysql/lib located. If I compile it with the options given above I only found these files in /usr/local/mysql/lib (MariaDB 10.2.6):

```
# ls -l /usr/local/mysql/lib/
total 3572
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2305518 Jul  4 08:14 libmariadbclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 08:31 libmariadb.so -> libmariadb.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1297664 Jul  4 08:14 libmariadb.so.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   48406 Jul  4 08:14 libmysqlservices.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul  4 08:31 plugin
```

How can I get libmysqlclient.so? There isn't also any libmariadbclient.so just libmariadbclient.a ...

Thank you for further hints!

Comment: Why are you expecting to build a mysql library from mariadb source?

Comment: MariaDB is an drop-in replacement as said on serveral websites.
I need the libmysqlclient.so library to link agains php 7.

Comment: Another reason is: I need mysql/mariadb with PHP... this is the ouput of my configure script of PHP:

`checking whether to enable embedded MySQLi support... no
checking for specified location of the MySQL UNIX socket... no
checking for mysql_set_server_option in -lmysqlclient_r... no
configure: error: wrong mysql library version or lib not found. Check config.log for more information.`

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I found a solution.
I've just did a symbolic link to libmariadb.so and it now looks like the following:

```
ls -l /usr/local/mysql/lib/
total 3572
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2305518 Jul  4 16:21 libmariadbclient.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 16:39 libmariadb.so -> libmariadb.so.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1297664 Jul  4 16:21 libmariadb.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 16:40 libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmariadb.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Jul  4 16:40 libmysqlclient.so -> libmariadb.so.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   48406 Jul  4 16:21 libmysqlservices.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Jul  4 16:39 plugin
```

In this case PHP 7 would finally find the mysql libraries...